# Change screen turning off behaviour on button press

Tags: shortcut-keys, screen

I'm working on an ASUS laptop, the N552VX model, with Ubuntu 16.04. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> combination turns the laptop screen off and on again.

But recently I noticed that in Windows 10, the screen will "awaken" again if I press any button or move the mouse or the cursor.

Is there any way to change the default behaviour to the same as in Windows, i.e. to "awaken" the screen on any input?

I didn't know any precise keywords to google for, so search was no big help. If this is a duplicate, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Does <Fn>+<F7> turn the screen off/on or put the laptop to sleep and wakeup?

Comment: It turns the screen off. A youtube video would continue to run with the screen off.